# How to conditionally set the app_name before Notification title(On Android 8.0)?

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

On Android 8.0, the default notification message will show an small Icon then app_name and content tile. There's no API available to set different app_name for notification. I have tried to use custom layout, but that's not work for status bar.

Also as the app_name statically assigned to a string on the xml. This seems very tough.

I just want to set different app_name based on some condition variable's value. Could anyone help on this issue? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

No, You cannot pretend to be someone else according to google play policy. So Android system has restricted you now from changing App Name in Notification.